# What is the correct structure for an SQL query that references multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with mutliple one to many tables. It contains questions and responses from different users.

When I want to select a specific set of responses, I find I am running multiple nested select queries on different tables.

This has always worked fine and seemed to do everything I needed it to - however the query I have just written has more nested queries than usual - and seems to be causing an internal server error (error log "mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 31 seconds").

I am wondering if my code structure is horribly inefficient and if there is a better way to achieve my query?

Here is my current SQL

```
SELECT response_value, fk_intervention_id, fk_question_id FROM responses_submitted where fk_intervention_id in (
    SELECT pk_intervention_id FROM interventions where fk_module_id = 4 and fk_country_id in 
        (SELECT fk_country_id from country_region where fk_region_id in
            (SELECT fk_region_id from country_region where fk_country_id = 25)
        )
    AND year=2013 ) 
AND fk_question_id in (119, 122, 100, 1363, 130, 119, 122, 125, 127, 126, 138, 140)
```

Worth noting: this runs fine in MySQL workbench, but when I run it via PDO it causes the time out.

Further note: simplifying the query (removing the final nested query) prevent the error, so it seems certain this is a timeout issue with the complexity of the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd refactor this into something like the following. It's more understandable than all of the sub-selects, however, I don't know if this will handle your performance issue. (I refactored by sight, so there may be errors)

```
SELECT response_value, fk_intervention_id, fk_question_id 
FROM responses_submitted 
INNER JOIN interventions ON responses_submitted.fk_intervention_id = interventions.pk_intervention_id
INNER JOIN country_region ON interventions.fk_country_id = country_region.fk_country_id
Where 
interventions.fk_module_id = 4
AND country_region.fk_country_id = 25
AND year = 2013
AND fk_question_id in (119, 122, 100, 1363, 130, 119, 122, 125, 127, 126, 138, 140)
```

Comment: Ok thanks! I don't really understand how to use JOINs so I'm going to have to learn to understand your code: it almost works, but selects all the responses for just one intervention in a region, rather than all the interventions in a region.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering if my code structure is horribly inefficient and if there is a better way to achieve my query?

Yes. And if you want to see how inefficient it is, place EXPLAIN EXTENDED in front of the query. My favorite resource for understanding the output of a MySQL explain query is http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/

inre your response to @jeremy above,

> I don't really understand how to use JOINs so I'm going to have to
>   learn to understand your code:

Okay so you definitely need to learn how to use joins if you're gonna use SQL for anything. It's fundamental. You will write horrible SQL and make horrible data modeling mistakes unless you understand joins. Please spend the time to learn and understand them

In terms of what your query should look like, it should look something like this:

```
SELECT response_value, fk_intervention_id, fk_question_id 
FROM responses_submitted AS a
INNER JOIN interventions AS b
    ON a.fk_intervention_id = b.pk_intervention_id
INNER JOIN country_region AS c
    ON b.fk_country_id = c.fk_country_id
WHERE a.fk_question_id IN (119, 122, 100, 1363, 130, 119, 122, 125, 127, 126, 138, 140)
AND b.fk_module_id = 4
AND b.year = 2013
AND c.fk_country_id = 25
```

I eyeballed @jeremy's query above and seems to be the same, although you mentioned that that result was inaccurate. Based on what you've shared, it shouldn't be. If it is, I would recommend troubleshooting it by determining if any of your join keys are many to many, eg,

```
SELECT fk_country_id, count(*) FROM country_region GROUP BY fk_country_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;   /*based on what you described, this should be null*/

SELECT pk_intervention_id, count(*) FROM interventions WHERE fk_module_id = 4 AND year = 2013 GROUP BY pk_intervention_id HAVING count(*) > 1; /*based on what you described, this should be null*/
```

etc

Last, I would highly recommend learning a bit more about MySQL indices and how they can be used for optimizing queries. Just eyeballing this, it would seem to me that index on

country_region.fk_country_id

responses.fk_question_id

interventions.pk_intervention_id

interventions.fk_module_id

would probably be a minimum.... although you could almost certainly optimize those quite a bit. Use the EXPLAIN query above and it can help you understand how.

Best of luck

Comment: This is incredibly helpful - thanks for taking the time to write it out.

I think the problem with Jeremy's code (not that it's his code, probably my structure) is that one of the tables I have is many-many. country_region takes make country ids and associates them with many region ids (I think this is correct as a country can be in multiple regions).

I'm going to study your comment some more.

Comment: Well unless the country_region table contains data needed to answer your question (eg in the top select query perhaps) it would seem to me that you could simply remove that table (and that join) entirely and just add a where clause on interventions.fk_country_id (so in my version of the query, remove the join to country_region and replace "AND c.fk_country_id = 25" with "AND b.fk_country_id = 25")